# processing a two dimentional array with MPI_Scatter and MPI_Gather

Tags: c, arrays, mpi

I'm trying to learn Mpi throught some examples.

After reading some  discutions about manipulating arrays with mpi , i saw that  the cells in two dimentional array are not contigous in memory ; So it could make the things harder.

supposing my 2d array is as follows :

```
1111
2222
3333
4444
```

I saw in one example that there is another way for allocating memory for a two dimentional array :

```
   int  *items = ( int *) malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(*items));
```

with the instruction above and  would be presented in memory as follows:

`111122223334444`.

My question is: how i can send a portion of the array to each processor, i know that there are many ways like  MPI_Scatter,but it's only for the same chunks size.

As an example I want to execute my program on n processors(let n=3) ,each processor will get the length of the array divided by 3 ;

in my example 16/3 = 5 celles for each processor:

```
11112  rank= 0
22233  rank= 1
334444 rank= 2
```

as we see the last processor will get a different size.

i saw that we can define our custom MPI_Scatter method with MPI_Scatterv but i'm wondering if there is a simple way to do that?

sending m chunks to every processor and the last processor could get a different size;i'm speaking only for the case where the last processor could get a different chunk size.

**So** my 3 processors has to do some calculation on the received data and they should return the modified buffer ,how i could use  MPI_Gather in this senario?

My processors should increment the values in the received buffer

```
22223  rank= 0
33344  rank= 1
445555 rank= 2
```

**-** how can i return the received  buffer  to the master processor?

Any help will be very welcomed.

Thank you.

Comment: if **only one** task should receive some extra cells, a simpler alternative is to `MPI_Scatter(5 cells)` followed by the root task sending the extra cell(s) to the special task..

Comment: if `root==0` and the root task should get more cells, you can `MPI_Scatter(items+1, 5 cells)`

Comment: sorry i didn't get your idea, just to note the number of processor and the size of the array is known only when the program is executed.the user choose the size and the number of processor.

Comment: do you mean that for the last processor i shoud send him the chanks two times? 5 cells for the first message and the extra extra cells for the second message?

Comment: the 5 chunks are received by `MPI_Scatter()` and the remaining cell is received by `MPI_Recv()`. i would not call `MPI_Scatter()` a message, so let's say the chunks are received in two phases.

Comment: so for the last processor i should have two buffer for upcoming data , is that a good idea?I mean the best way is to have only one buffer receiving that upcoming data.do you have any idea?another problee is i would like to return the buffer to the master processor ,will it be complicated with  Mpi_gather ?

Comment: i edited my question to clear things ; thank you

Comment: no need for two buffers. simply allocate a larger buffer on the last task, and `MPI_Recv()` at the 5th element (since you `MPI_Scatter()` 5 elements). Things would be much easier if you let `rank=0` handle extra elements (in that case, simply offset the send buffer)

Comment: to be complete, if rank zero should have the extra cells, `MPI_IN_PLACE` has to be used.